# Merging dataframes with different indexes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have 2 dataframes that i would like to merge but i am unable to get it to work like i want.

```
       ExitType      ExitSignal     ExitTime  ExitPrice
0           NaN             NaN          NaN        NaN
1     ExitShort   Profit Target   7:00:00 AM     2.8065
2           NaN             NaN          NaN        NaN
3     ExitShort   Profit Target   8:00:00 AM     2.7772
4           NaN             NaN          NaN        NaN
5     ExitShort   Profit Target   8:30:00 AM     2.7533
6           NaN             NaN          NaN        NaN
7     ExitShort       Stop Loss  10:00:00 AM     2.7700
8           NaN             NaN          NaN        NaN
9      ExitLong       Stop Loss   9:30:00 AM     2.8135
10          NaN             NaN          NaN        NaN
11    ExitShort   Profit Target   6:30:00 AM     2.7200
[5816 rows x 4 columns]
```

and this dataframe is the 'entries'

```
      Trade #  Order #        Type Signal       Date         Time   Price  \
0           1        1  EntryShort  PChSE   1/7/2008   7:00:00 AM  2.8304   
2           2        3  EntryShort  PChSE   1/7/2008   7:30:00 AM  2.8011   
4           3        5  EntryShort  PChSE   1/7/2008   8:00:00 AM  2.7772   
6           4        7  EntryShort  PChSE   1/7/2008   8:30:00 AM  2.7533   
8           5        9   EntryLong  PChLE   1/9/2008   8:30:00 AM  2.8302   
10          6       11  EntryShort  PChSE  1/10/2008   5:30:00 AM  2.7439 
[2908 rows x 16 columns]
```

i would like to take the columns from the "exits" dataframe and add them to the "entries" dataframe and not include the rows with "NaN" values. For example the "extries" dataframe line 0 should add the columns from the 'exits' datarame at row 1.

How can i do that?

Comment: Without `Trade #` or `Order #` in your exits dataframe, you have no way to join your tables.  Although the exits is twice the size of the entries, so perhaps there is an unstated order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that there appears to be an unstated order to your tables in that every other row in exits matches the corresponding row in entries, you can try this:

```
pd.concat([entries, exits.dropna()], axis=1)
```

Comment: this worked after doing a reset_index() on both dataframes.